# file_put_content...fail to open stream:Permission denied in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

The error is mention in below:-

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 81:
   file_put_contents(/var/www/html/Training-management-system/storage/framework/views/bcb68ba8b65b7fabca5fe88709fb00b6): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I can google itbut not get the exact solution. SO I am thankful if anyone help me to solve it out.

Comment: Laravel needs permissions to write in storage. Take a look here http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/43/changing-storage-path-permissions and let us know if this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

is a file permissions issue as   lesssugar said , you need to give writte permissions to the storage folder , so go to your html/Tranining-management-system.. folder an then you can do :

```
chmod -R 0777 storage/
```

That will change to writte access Recursively .

Please read the configuration section in docs :

http://laravel.com/docs/master#configuration

You have to do the same with the cache folder.

Comment: It also worked for me removing the existing files in `storage/framework/views`

Comment: `chmod -R 775 storage/` also works for me. If you use `laravel/passport`, don't forget to use `chmod 664 storage/*.key` for oauth keys

Comment: Could this possibly open up security concerns?

Comment: I dont understand why this comment has been approved and has so many upvotes. 777 permissions is a massive security risk as people outside of www-data group can manipulate the files in the directory.

The appropriate method would be to ensure it has the correct write perms or run php artisan view:cache accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

I run `php artisan view:cache` and it solved the issue

Comment: For me, It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error with the view file cache. Please run `php artisan view:cache`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with **Laravel** running in a docker container. I checked and the **www-data** group didn't had permissions nor ownership on the directory.

The **chown** command allows you to change the user and/or group ownership of a given directory.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data storage/
```

Keep in mind that `chmod -R 777 storage/` permissions is a massive security risk. Normally users outside www-data group should not be able to manipulate files. This is just a workaround for development environments and should be avoided on production environments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solutions but didn't get resolved this error.

`Just:` I have just created **views folder** in `'storage/framework'` and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I try run php artisan view:cache and it solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it as I was only granting permission to via this command:

Copy Code

```
sudo chmod -R 775 storage/framework/views
```

The fix was to add this:

Copy Code

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw storage  storage/framework/views
```