# laravel cache failed to open stream: No such file or directory framework/views

Tags: caching, laravel-5

I use laravel 5.4. a clear cache after update config file. that appear like this error.

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 111:
file_put_contents(/home/web_user/webhosts/mufer/backend.mufer.local/storage/framework/views/318a49f22562be3fc1c86c88ecc141c22e`8fed4e.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`
```

Then i try to fixed using following command:

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

and:

[file_put_content...fail to open stream:Permission denied in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099001/file-put-content-fail-to-open-streampermission-denied-in-laravel-5)

Some answer are said craete /storage/framework  sub folders and then composer update. but that also not working.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM3xV.png)

Then i run `composer dump-autoload
and`composer update`.

But problem not solved..

Comment: Did you find an answer to that issue? Happend I just ran into the same thing..

Answer (score 7):

**Perhaps you are using Homestead?**

I ran into this problem when using Homestead. Basically, when you are using Homestead and run the `php artisan config:cache` command out of your virtual machine, the cache paths get broken.

I solved it login via ssh to Homestead `vagrant ssh` and running `php artisan config:cache` from there.

Answer (score 4):

My solution was to chmod `/storage/framework/views` directory to 777.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and my mistake was so simple it's hilarious.

I forgot to `git add` one of my files. So on the backend, it was trying to get this `file.php` but it didn't exist. It's usually quite descriptive in the error, except, I was running a job that jumps on a queue. All of a sudden, that helpful exception no longer exists :D

So in order to fix it, I had to:

`git add -A
git commit -m "blah blah"
git push`

On the server, I needed to:

`git pull
composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me gently:

```
php artisan view:cache
```