# Laravel file_put_contents() error

Tags: php, laravel

I have a website which works locally (through VM), but when I upload it to the server I get this error

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 111:

file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/Code/xxxx/storage/framework/sessions
/Ec2ceBoBBnKIOx8SzMXOf4akbzA5g5aI9WHBEhn6): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Things I've tried that didn't help: running `composer update`, running `dump-autoload`, running `cache:clear`, running `config:cache`, deleting everything on server and re-uploading everything after, creating directory/file manually, setting permissions to 777.

Any insights?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169892/errorexception-in-filesystem-php try this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099001/file-put-content-fail-to-open-streampermission-denied-in-laravel-5.... you are facing permission issues

Comment: whats the base directory of the project on the VM?

Comment: @BilalAhmed - I already tried setting permissions, it is written in my question.

Comment: @mbozwood /home/vagrant/Code/xxxx

Comment: @Norgul definitely did a recursive chmod on the storage folder? is the storage folder blank? Laravel doesnt create the directories so stores blank gitignores in them to ensure the directories remain over git? I cant think of anything else.

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? 
or still hanging on it.

Comment: As far as I remember, I didn't solve it. It wasn't a crucial thing so I just dropped it